# sidebar menu not collapsing automatically in mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar menu which is working fine in desktop and tablets. But having issues in mobile devices. The sidebar menu is not collapsing automatically in mobiles. It is closing only when I click on the toggle, but that should close automatically when I click on anywhere outside the menu or it should close when the route changes.

Here's some code.

app-menu.js

```
      $('.navbar-header, .main-menu').on('mouseenter',modernMenuExpand).on('mouseleave',modernMenuCollapse);

  function modernMenuExpand(){
    alert('first');
    if( $body.data('menu') == 'vertical-menu-modern'){
      $('.main-menu, .navbar-header').addClass('expanded');
      if($body.hasClass('menu-collapsed')){
        var $listItem = $('.main-menu li.menu-collapsed-open'),
        $subList = $listItem.children('ul');

        $subList.hide().slideDown(200, function() {
            $(this).css('display', '');
        });

        $listItem.addClass('open').removeClass('menu-collapsed-open');
        // $.app.menu.changeLogo('expand');
      }
    }
  }

  function modernMenuCollapse(){
    alert('second');
    if($body.hasClass('menu-collapsed') && $body.data('menu') == 'vertical-menu-modern'){
      setTimeout(function(){
        if($('.main-menu:hover').length === 0 && $('.navbar-header:hover').length === 0){

          $('.main-menu, .navbar-header').removeClass('expanded');
          if($body.hasClass('menu-collapsed')){
            var $listItem = $('.main-menu li.open'),
            $subList = $listItem.children('ul');
            $listItem.addClass('menu-collapsed-open');

            $subList.show().slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).css('display', '');
            });

            $listItem.removeClass('open');
            // $.app.menu.changeLogo();
          }
        }
      },1);
    }
  }
```

sidebar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteInfo } from './sidebar.metadata';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

declare var $: any;
@Component({
    // moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-sidebar',
    templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
})

export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        $.getScript('./assets/app/js/core/app-menu.js');
        $.getScript('./assets/app/js/core/app.js');
    }

}
```

html

```
<!-- Sidebar Content starts -->
<div id="stackMenu" data-scroll-to-active="true" class="main-menu menu-fixed menu-light menu-accordion menu-shadow">
  <!-- main menu content-->
  <div class="main-menu-content">
    <ul id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation" class="navigation navigation-main">
      <li>
        <a routerLink="dashboard">
          <span class="menu-title">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a routerLink="list">
          <span class="menu-title">List</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a routerLink="maps">
          <span class="menu-title">Main maps</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a routerLink="components">
          <span class="menu-title">Components</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a routerLink="settings">
            <span class="menu-title">Settings</span>
          </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if need more additional information.

Comment: When the mouse leaves, on mobile? Most mobile devices do not have a mouse, can you elaborate which behaviour are you trying to get?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry for confusion. It should close when I click anywhere outside the menu or it should close when the route changes

Comment: There is a touchstart event that records touches on mobile. Use it on your content div, or for a wider extend any div that is not your menu, to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the touchstart event to any div that is not your menu, which in turn means if anything but the menu is touched it will close.

```
$('div').not('#main-menu-navigation').on('touchstart', function(){ 
    // close menu
});
```

Comment: If I want to add this touchstart event to menu only when the route changes?

Comment: Do you want the menu to close on route change on mobile and not on click on the content, or let the user only be able to close the menu if the route has changed?

Comment: I actually want to close the menu on click on the content

Comment: So when I tried this $('div').not('#main-menu-navigation').on('touchstart', function(){
        console.log('closed')
        $('.main-menu').removeClass('expanded');
    }); the menu is not collapsing when clicked anywhere but the console.log prints

Comment: You could just add the menu close code either in your route change function, or on click of the links $('#main-menu-navigation li a').click(function(){ //close menu });

Comment: You forgot your semicolon after the console.log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171786/discussion-between-yer-and-sirence).